# Continuous limsup, Discrete limsup relation

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Is it true that for a real function f:
$$
\limsup_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \sup_{(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (t_n) \to \infty}\limsup_{t_n \to \infty} f(t_n)
$$
?

Where the first limsup is seen in the continuous sense and the second in a discrete sense.

I'm interested in this kind of properties as I'm working on some Brownian Motion proofs where I need easy ways for manipulating both kinds of limsup. I'm not directly interested in the proof of the result but rather on it's truthfulness. Still any intuition or sketch of proof is welcome...

What useful characterizations allow one to work and move between both kinds of limsup without much trouble?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

not generally, the discrete version loses too much information to work with $\lim\sup$. take for instance the function $f=\sin x$, sequence $t_n=2 \pi n$. it might work better with Brownian motion-type functions, since my example comes from the periodicity.